# Tailing a log within Laravel never executes Symfony Process callback

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, process, laravel-6

I'm trying to tail a log file using a console command to detect specific errors. However, the call back in the `run(...)` portion of my script is never called in the Symfony Process:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class MonitorLogs extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'monitor:logs {log}';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $command = "tail -n 1 -f " . escapeshellarg($this->argument('log'));

        (new Process($command))
            ->setTty(true)
            ->setTimeout(null)
            ->run(function ($type, $line) {
                $this->info('test');
            });
    }
}
```

I tried tracing with Xdebug any my break point at `$this->info()` is never reached. I can add lines to the log file I am testing with and they show up in my console while the script is running, but that line to output the word `test` is never hit.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `setTty(true)` and the output should display accordingly